# Can we get data type of a field value from Firestore DB using Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a JSON document from Firestore DB using java. I need to know the data type of the fields(values of json keys) in the JSON. Is there any way to know if a field value in Json is a String/Boolean/Number?

Comment: No, you should get to know before fetch. And fetch exact type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a certain way. It's not exactly checking the type of a JSON field but getting the value's `Object` and checking its class. You will not interact with the JSON representing the document, but the document's snapshot.

To do so, you could use the [`get`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get-java.lang.String-) method to retrieve the value and read the object's class. For example:

```
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> query = db.collection("collection").get();
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = query.get();
List<QueryDocumentsnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
    Object field = document.get("field");

    System.out.println("Document: " + document.getId());
    System.out.println("Field: " + field + " (" + field.getClass() + ")");
    System.out.println("----------");
}
```

Which would result in something like this:

```sh
Document: aaaaa
Field: hey (class java.lang.String)
----------
Document: bbbbb
Field: true (class java.lang.Boolean)
----------
Document: ccccc
Field: 99 (class java.lang.Long)
----------
```

As it can be seen, the field's class can be retrieved by retrieving the field as an `Object` and then checking its class. The [`get`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get-java.lang.String-) method exists precisely for the purpose of getting the value regardless of its type, but I'd still recommend using the specific methods (e.g. [`getString`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getString-java.lang.String-)) whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(document.get("fieldname").getClass().getSimpleName());
```

prints something like:

field name : geo

field type : GeoPoint

field name : number

field type : Long

field name : field1

field type : String

field name : array

field type : ArrayList

field name : time

field type : Timestamp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).